# Scan uploaded files for viruses

Tags: file-uploads, secure

Is there anyway to scan uploaded files for viruses? Or is there a solution to scan files on the server? If not, this would be an awesome add-on, if someone were to create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my servers I use [Clam AntiVirus](http://www.clamav.net/). It is free, have good db and has *[clamscan](http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/html/node32.html)*  which can be used with system commands.

- For integration native upload need to make ext. used hook
  [file_after_save](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/filemanager/index.html#file-after-save).
- For Playa - [assets_upload_file](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/developers/hooks/upload_file.html)

Based on pass/fail indication which *clamscan* is return, make decision - keep it or delete it.

Comment: This looks like it could work, if this designer turned web developer could understand the documentation. I'll look into this with the help of a friend who is a real programmer.